# MassTransit how to handle Start/Stop when Queue is down

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am using RabbitMQ 3.6.0 with MasstTransit 3.2.0 and configure it as following:

```
// MassTransit
IBusControl bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
{
    var host = cfg.Host(new Uri(configuration.Url), h =>
    {
        h.Username(configuration.User.UserName);
        h.Password(configuration.User.Password);
    });

    cfg.UseXmlSerializer();

    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, configuration.Queue, e =>
    {
    });
});
```

And I start it as following:

```
// start the bus
IBusControl bus = container.Resolve<IBusControl>();
bus.Start();
```

Unfortunately when RabbitMQ is down, and this is a scenario I have in my architecture, the method `bus.Start()` hang for a while until it bombs and throw an exception.
Is there an alternative pattern that I can use so the application notifies via "log" that the Queue is down and I can try later to run `bus.Start()`?

Comment: Not sure if there is anything in MassTransit (would think so), but I would just keep retrying. If you can't do anything about it, when keep trying until it is fixed. Maybe even with a longer and longer retry interval.

Comment: So, a sort of recursive pattern that keep trying to connect, maybe on a separated thread so that it doesn't block the application startup?
And what about an app that has only a message consumer?

Comment: It depends on how you want you system to react in case RabbitMQ is down. If you need to take an action (restart it), then blowing may be the best way. If RabbitMQ at some points fixes itself, then retrying may be the best solution. You could also let the applications retry for a certain amount of attempts before blowing up. We are also using RabbitMQ, and sometimes the connection aborts, typical consumers, and then we just try again.

Comment: You may be able to use a transient-fault handling library like Polly https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/ to orchestrate the retry aspect, including with exponential backoff [disclosure: I lead on this library].  Depending how much control MassTransit gives you over this aspect.  You then need to decide (as others have said) whether to start up your process with RabbitMQ unavailable (and somehow store failing message operations for later processing), or whether to blow (fail to start your process) on RabbitMQ unavailable after suitable retries.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to manually retry `bus.Start()` as if you handle the exception thrown (`RabbitMqConnectionException`), MassTransit (we're using v3.5.5) will keep on trying to establish a RabbitMQ connection in the background. Calling `bus.Start()` a second time will always succeed even if RabbitMQ is still unavailable.

In this scenario we catch the exception thrown on `bus.Start()` and evaluate it to see if it's a transient or permanent fault. If its permanent then terminate the application. If its transient then we start the application and then use [Polly](http://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) to retry any important `bus.Publish()`/`bus.Send()` calls that fail whilst RabbitMQ is offline.